# Identifying edge cases of a one-dimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, graph

I'm creating a 2-dimensional heat map which has functionality when you click on any pixel. It grabs data associated with the index of every pixel (**including adjacent pixels**) and plots it. It currently looks like this:

[image]

The problem that I'm encountering is when I click on a left or right edge pixel, since it grabs data from adjacent pixels, it can retrieve data from the opposite side of the graph since it is all within a one-dimensional array. I am trying to create a conditional which checks if the clicked pixel is an edge case, and then configures the magnified graph accordingly to not show points from the other side of the main graph. This is the code I have so far:

```
// pushes all dataMagnified arrays left and right of i to magMainStore
var dataGrabber = function(indexGrabbed, arrayPushed) {

  // iterates through all 5 pixels being selected
  for (var b = -2; b <= 2; b++) {

    var divValue = toString(i / cropLength + b);

    // checks if selected index exists, and if it is not in the prior row, or if it is equal to zero
    if (dataMagnified[indexGrabbed + b] != undefined && (& divValue.indexOf(".")!=-1)) {
      dataMagnified[indexGrabbed + b].forEach(function(z) {
        arrayPushed.push(z);
      })
    }
  }
};
```

I am trying to get the same result as if I had a two dimensional array, and finding when the adjacent values within a single array is undefined. This is the line where I'm creating a conditional for that

```
if (dataMagnified[indexGrabbed + b] != undefined && (& divValue.indexOf(".")!=-1)) {
```

The second condition after the and is my attempts so far trying to figure this out. I'm unsure if I can even do this within a for loop that iterates 5 times or if I have to create multiple conditions for this. In addition, here's an image displaying what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: [Here's the entire codebase](https://github.com/AstroBoogie/BL-files/blob/master/BL_waterfall/js/backup.js) if variables are unclear.

Comment: Using a 1d arry for 320x200x256 graphics, the indices of the pixels on the left-edge of the screen were 0,320,640,960 - i.e every width pixels,with those on the right being found at width-1, (2*width)-1, etc, etc. So, you'll need to be careful for indices that are [width-1..width]. For what it's worth, loop-unrolling is an optimization that compilers (often) apply. They turn quick to read/write code (loops) into quick to execute code (repeated identical or near identical code).

Comment: @enhzflep So I think I've organized my thoughts [as pseudocode](http://pastebin.com/cDriBUb5), however I'm not sure how to implement it with the rest of my for loop. Should I create separate if statements for everything or is there a better way to do it? Also, I'm unsure what loop-unrolling is. Should I implement loop-unrolling or does JS do it by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks overly complex and will perform rather slowly. For example, converting numbers to strings to be able to use `.indexOf()` to find a decimal point just for the sake of checking for integer numbers doesn't seem right.

A much simpler and more elegant solution might be the following function which will return the selection range bounded by the limits of the row:

```
function getBoundedSelection(indexGrabbed, selectionWidth) {
  return dataMagnified.slice(
    Math.max(Math.floor(indexGrabbed/cropLength) * cropLength, indexGrabbed - selectionWidth),
    Math.min(rowStartIndex + cropLength, indexGrabbed + selectionWidth)
  );
}
```

Here, to keep it as flexible as possible, `selectionWidth` determines the width of the selected range to either side of `indexGrabbed`. This would be *2* in your case.

As an explanation of what this does, I have broken it down:

```
function getBoundedSelection(indexGrabbed, selectionWidth) {
    // Calculate the row indexGrabbed is on.
    var row = Math.floor(indexGrabbed/cropLength);

    // Determine the first index on that row.
    var rowStartIndex = row * cropLength;

    // Get the start index of the selection range or the start of the row,
    // whatever is larger.
    var selStartIndex = Math.max(rowStartIndex, indexGrabbed - selectionWidth);

    // Determine the last index on that row
    var rowEndIndex = rowStartIndex + cropLength;

    // Get the end index of the selection range or the end of the row,
    //whatever is smaller.
    var selEndIndex = Math.min(rowEndIndex, indexGrabbed + selectionWidth);

    // Return the slice bounded by the row's limits.
    return  dataMagnified.slice(selStartIndex, selEndIndex);  
}
```

Comment: Elegant solution! I would've never thought of that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

So I discovered that since the results of the clicked position would create a variable start and end position in the for loop, the only way to do this was as follows:

I started the same; all the code is nested in one function:

```
var dataGrabber = function(indexGrabbed, arrayPushed) {
```

I then create a second function that takes a start and end point as arguments, then passes them as the for loop starting point and ending condition:

```
var magnifyCondition = function (start, end) {
    for (var b = start; b <= end; b++) {
        if (dataMagnified[indexGrabbed + b] != undefined) {
            dataMagnified[indexGrabbed + b].forEach(function (z) {
                arrayPushed.push(z);
            })
        }
    }
};
```

After that, I created 5 independent conditional statements since the start and end points can't be easily iterated through:

```
    if (((indexGrabbed - 1) / cropLength).toString().indexOf(".") == -1) {
        magnifyCondition(-1, 2);
    }
    else if ((indexGrabbed / cropLength).toString().indexOf(".") == -1) {
        magnifyCondition(0, 2);
    }
    else if (((indexGrabbed + 1) / cropLength).toString().indexOf(".") == -1) {
        magnifyCondition(-2, 0);
    }
    else if (((indexGrabbed + 2) / cropLength).toString().indexOf(".") == -1) {
        magnifyCondition(-2, 1);
    }
    else {
        magnifyCondition(-2, 2);
    }
};
```

Lastly, I pass the index grabbed (i of the on clicked function) and an arbitrary array where the values get stored.

```
dataGrabber(i, magMainStore);
```

If there's a better way instead of the if statements, please let me know and I'd be happy to organize it better in the future!